# How to combine event listeners with "asking" for an event?

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface

I wrote a simple little maze game for a terminal which repeatedly asks the user to do something (e.g. "In which direction would you like to go? [N/E/S/W]"). I have a `navigate()` method running in a loop that fires off these questions, stores their answers and does something depending on the answer.

```
public enum Dir (N, E, S, W);

public void navigate() {
    Dir nextDir = utils.askDirection("Which way do you want to go?");
    // Do stuff with answer, like changing position of user in maze
}
```

Now, I've written a simple GUI for my game. I deliberately put all the references to the terminal in a `ConsoleUtils` class which implements a `Utils` interface (this has methods like `askQuestion()`) - the idea being that I could create a `GuiUtils` class and have my game *either* as a terminal game *or* as a GUI game.

The problem is that the `navigate` method asks the user a question and then "waits" for the response, which the `Utils` class gives it by using a `Scanner` to read the newest line of input. However if I use Event Listeners for the new N/E/S/W buttons in my GUI, they fire off events regardless whether the `navigate` method has asked for one or not.
[--> Image of GUI](http://imgur.com/1JrhN9c)

Is there any way I can combine this or do I need to write a new `navigate` method for the GUI?

(To be honest, I'm also not entirely sure whether my GUI class should instantiate a `game` class, in which case the logic for `navigate` could end up in a GUI method anyway, or whether the game should have a GUI. I haven't written any code for the event listener either yet, since I'm not sure which class should be calling which. This is probably a separate question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text based game has a loop that repeatedly asks questions to gather user input. Swing provides this loop for you by continually executing `Runnable` blocks of code that have been posted to the [`EventQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). For example, when the user presses a [button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) labeled <kbd>E</kbd>, code is posted to the queue that invokes your `ActionEvent` implementation to handle your game's interpretation of the `move east` command.

For reference, a complete example of a very simple guessing game is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). In pseudocode, the corresponding text based game might look like this:

```
initialize
loop
    prompt "Guess what color!"
    get chosenColor
    if chosenColor = actualColor
        say "You win!"
        reset game
    else
        say "Keep trying."
end loop
```

A more elaborate [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) cited there includes the original text-based source.